# Get Orientation without autorotation in Cocos2d Project

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, orientation, landscape, portrait

I have a small issue and I can't find any solution. How can I turn off autorotation for views and ogl and still get Orientation?

For example if I set `GAME_AUTOROTATION` to `kGameAutorotationNone` the notification center `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` doesn't work.
If I allow in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` two orientations autorotation appear again. If I implement a blank `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` nothing change.

So, how can I get orientations change without actually rotate anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage your own orientation method by rotating your Current CCLayer/CCScene. on willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method. But make sure, you will get WRONG touch pixels on all 3 touch events..! You have to modify the touch-cordinates according to your orientation them before taking them in calculations.